# Using CLLocationManager() in viewDidLoad() prevents MKMapView from being dragged or zoomed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The map view refuses to be dragged or zoomed in/out with the following code.

Theres a number of things I've tried. I've allowed all the necessary properties in the attributes inspector and even tried adding the `isZoomEnabled` and other properties but with no luck.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var courseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations[0]

        self.latitudeLabel.text = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
        self.longitudeLabel.text = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
        self.courseLabel.text = String(location.course)
        self.speedLabel.text = String(location.speed)
        self.altitudeLabel.text = String(location.altitude)

        let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.10
        let longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.10
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: span)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }

            else {
                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                    var address = ""

                    if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                        address += placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "
                    }

                    if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                        address += placemark.thoroughfare! + "\n"
                    }

                    if placemark.subLocality != nil {
                        address += placemark.subLocality! + "\n"
                    }

                    if placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                        address += placemark.subAdministrativeArea! + "\n"
                    }

                    if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                        address += placemark.postalCode! + "\n"
                    }

                    if placemark.country != nil {
                        address += placemark.country! + " "
                    }

                    self.addressLabel.text = address

                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Where should this code go or what could be edited to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Usually you can't do `startUpdatingLocation()` until the user has authorized access. Also make sure you set the `NSLocationWhenIsUseUsageDescription` key-value in your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: @Paolo Already did those things. Theres no error. I just can't drag the zoom the map.

Comment: `CLLocationManager` has nothing to do with `MKMapView`, the two work completely independently, so you have to look for the issue elsewhere. Please include the code, where you handle your mapview.

Comment: @DávidPásztor updated question to show the full code.

Comment: You are setting the region of the map view every time the location updates. It's not that you can't scroll/zoom, it's just that every time you do it gets reset to the region you're creating in the `didUpdateLocations` function because a new location is coming in.

Comment: @Paolo is there a way to prevent that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map view's region is being set every time the location updates, preventing you from interacting with the map in a meaningful way.

One way to prevent this is to set a `Bool` indicating that the region has already been set and to not set it again.

```
var regionHasBeenSet = false

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { 
    // ...

    if !regionHasBeenSet {
        let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.10
        let longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.10
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: span)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        regionHasBeenSet = true
    }

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
        // ...
    }
}
```

And if you want the map's region to be centered on the location again, just change `regionHasBeenSet` to `false` whenever and on the next location update the region will be reset.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for your help.